# Devise Unpermitted parameter nested form

Tags: forms, devise, nested

I have a user model `parent` and and child model `patient`. I want to add patient related attributes in the patients model through devise(user) signup form, but the data is not saving in patient model.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def new
        build_resource({})
    resource.build_patient
    respond_with self.resource  
    end

    def create
    super
  end


end
private
 def sign_up_params
    params.require(resource_name).permit(:email, [patient_attributes:[:user_id, :phone, :address,:age]], :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

This is my user and patient models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :patient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient
end
#####
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

This is the nested form:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :patient do |p| %>

    phone <%= p.text_field :phone %>

    address <%= p.text_field :address %>

    age <%= p.text_field :age %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

When I fill the form and click submit button these are the params:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"b+5GjScdG1gSnPL1eRDMW9U6tWiL1+liJMHvBCWYO2DEqRPJIBKzpXE3HGHlDgJPVcB+ro3ZVi+fHmNCdri1Zw==", "user"=>{"username"=>"q", "email"=>"kh1@gmail.com", "patient_attributes"=>{"phone"=>"444444", "address"=>"lllllllll", "age"=>"55"}, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_type"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
**Unpermitted parameter: patient_attributes**
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is simple
i add parameters is like this in application controller

**devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do 
      |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username,:user_type,patient_attributes: [:user_id, :phone, :address,:age])
    end**

and change form little bit

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :patient, Patient.new do |p| %>
    </br>
    phone <%= p.text_field :phone %>
     </br>
    address <%= p.text_field :address %>
     </br>
    age <%= p.text_field :age %>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you.**
Just remove square bracket from `[patient_attributes:[:user_id, :phone, :address,:age]]`

and use

```
patient_attributes:[:user_id, :phone, :address,:age]
```

only. This should help you.